# How to make a specific prefab rotate on button press?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am designing a game and in the current scene that I am designing there are around 100 prefabs. 
[image]

> The pic above shows how an object would usually look.

What I want to do is when I press the red button, I want the car model in the middle to rotate. 
With debug.Log I've understood that when I press F(use) I want that specific object to rotate.

What I have done so far is in terms of code is :

```
        private void SearchForObject()
        {
            if (!m_ItemCoolDown)
            {
                if (m_Target != null)
                {
                    if (m_Target.tag == m_InteractWithObjectsTag)
                    {
                        if (m_WeaponUI != null)
                            m_WeaponUI.ShowPickupMessage("PRESS <color=#FF9200FF>" + m_UseKey + "</color> TO INTERACT WITH THE OBJECT");

                        if (InputManager.GetButtonDown("Use"))
                        {


                            Debug.Log("Button pressed");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But how can I make the code realize that I want that object to rotate?

> there are around 100 more objects like this, that when I go to them, and press F, I want them to rotate too..

I was thinking is to create a script, and attach it to the button, and attach the car model to it, something like this :
[image]

and when I press F, I want the script to go to this other script, grab the specific model and then rotate. But I am not sure how to do this, does anyone have any idea?

thanks

Comment: rotate a specific amount, time? When should it stop to rotate? How exactly is your button setup? Should it be a toggle so it keeps rotating until you press again or stop on its own or stop if you are not pressing the button anymore?

Comment: @derHugo rotate 360*. make a full rotation. button has nothing in it, just a empty script. be a Toggle, and just press it once and when it does a full rotation it will stop

Answer (score 0):

I assume your script basically does what it should.

I would take what you already mentioned and let the button itself store the reference to its target object and handle the rotation.

For the rotation you can use a simple [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html):

```c#
public class ButtonScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The object that should rotate
    public Transform ObjectToTransform;

    // How long it should take to rotate in seconds
    public float RotationDuration = 1;

    // flag for making sure you can start rotating only if not already rotating
    private bool _isRotating;

    public void StartRotating()
    {
        // if already rotating do nothing
        if(_isRotating) return;

        StartCoroutine(Rotate());
    }

    // Rotates the ObjectToTransform 360° around its world up vector
    // in RotationDuration seconds
    private IEnumerator Rotate()
    {
        // set the flag so rotation can not be started multiple times
        _isRotating= true;

        // store the original rotation the target object currently has
        var initialRotation = ObjectToTransform.rotation;

        // we can already calculate the rotation speed in angles / second
        var rotationspeed = 360 / RotationDuration;

        // Rotate the object until the given duration is reached
        var timePassed = 0;    
        while(timePassed < RotationDuration)
        {
            // Time.deltaTime gives you the time passed since the last frame in seconds 
            // So every frame turn the object around world Y axis a little
            ObjectToTransform.Rotate(0, rotationspeed  * Time.deltaTime, 0, Space.World);

            // add the time passed since the last frame to the timePassed            
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

            // yield makes the Courutine interupt here so the frame can be rendered 
            // but the it "remembers" at which point it left
            // so in the next frame it goes on executing the code from the next line
            yield return null;
        }

        // Just to be sure we end with a clean rotation reset to the initial rotation in the end
        // since +360°  
        ObjectToTransform.rotation = initialRotation;

        // reset the flag so rotation can be started again
        _isRotating= false;
    }
}
```

So I also assume that `m_Target` is the specific "button" you want to press, right than all that is left now is to start the Coroutine on that button:

```c#
private void SearchForObject()
{
    if (!m_ItemCoolDown)
    {
        if (m_Target != null)
        {
            if (m_Target.tag == m_InteractWithObjectsTag)
            {
                if (m_WeaponUI != null)
                    m_WeaponUI.ShowPickupMessage("PRESS <color=#FF9200FF>" + m_UseKey + "</color> TO INTERACT WITH THE OBJECT");

                if (InputManager.GetButtonDown("Use"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Button pressed");

                    // if m_Target is not the button you'll have to get a reference
                    // to the button somehow
                    m_Target.GetComponent<ButtonScript>.StartRotating();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And set the reference of `targetObject` in the inspector to the object that should get rotated. Or if it is a prefab that gets initiaized you can do something like

```c#
var obj = Initialize(prefab /*, parameters if you have some*/);
// ButtonObject is the reference to your button GameObject
ButtonObject.GetComponent<ButtonScript>().targetObject = obj.transform;
```